# error invalid conversion from 'const X*' to 'X*'

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, virtual

I have this piece of code:

```
class C
{
    virtual vec3 f1(const A* a, B* b){...}
    virtual vec3 f2(A const* a, B const* b)
    {
        vec3 color = f1(a, b);
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to call `f1` from `f2`, but I don't know how to pass b in the correct way.
Now on compiling, I get:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const B*' to 'B* [-fpermissive]'
```

I've tried `vec3 color = f1(a, const_cast<B *>(b));`

This compiles, but then I get a segmentation fault on execution.

Please note that I can not change any function signature.
I can also not change the definition of `A` or `B` to implement a `getCopy()` function for instance.

**UPDATE:**

I found a function that returns a modified copy of b, so my problem is solved.
Thank you all for convincing me to stop trying to cast it directly into f1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't change the function signatures you can't solve your problem. Logically `f2` is making a contract with the caller: "I will take a B* and use it, but I guarantee I won't modify the `B` it's pointing to". If you then pass that pointer to something else that *does* modify the `B` you have broken the contract. If `f2` is intended to modify the `B`, the `B*` it takes shouldn't be `const` (and perhaps it should be a `B&`, as a side note).

And as for the crash: Modifying an object originally declared as `const` is undefined behavior. Realistically this means the compiler is free to do something like store it in read only memory, and other tricky things. If you then try to write to it, all bets are off. It can crash. It can work. Anything can happen.

Comment: Would a solution be to make a copy of B, and pass that pointer? Clearly when the function returns, you don't want B to have changed. I agree it's a conundrum...

Comment: That would be weird since, if the second function modifies the pointer, I would assume that is because the caller *wants* that new value. Or, if it doesn't, then why is it being modified?

Comment: @CmdrMoozy - valid point. But that's essentially what the signatures are telling you. I am thinking this is an "academic exercise".

Answer (score 2):

The only logical solution would be

```
virtual vec3 f2(A const* a, B const* b)
{
    B mutableB(*b);
    vec3 color = f1(a, &mutableB);
    ...
}
```

The run-time is free to crash because modifying a previously `const` declared variable after a `const_cast` is undefined behavior. And I'm guessing `b` is originally `const`, and `f1` tries to modify it.

Think about it from the compiler's POV: you want two functions - `f1` and `f2`. You can pass constant parameters to `f2`, thus guaranteeing you're not going to modify them. But then you try to pass them to `f1`, which *can* modify them.

Answer (score 1):

If `f1` modifies the pointer's target, then so does `f2`; so `f2` can't take a pointer to `const` object. You'll have to remove the `const` from `f2`, and not try to call it with a constant object. You're not allowed to modify `const` objects, and the program could crash (or otherwise have undefined behaviour) if you try to.

If `f1` doesn't modify it, then change that pointer to `const`. It sounds like it does, though.